# Data.Serialize cannot decode encoded bytes

Tags: haskell

Why does the simple encode/decode test fail in GHCI as shown below? I am using the [cereal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-0.5.8.1) library.

```
λ> import Data.Serialize
λ> decode (encode 5) :: Either String Int
Left "too few bytes\nFrom:\tdemandInput\n\n"
```

Comment: Never used the library, so I can't offer an in depth explanation but this works for me: `decode (encode (5 :: Int)) :: Either String Int` so I guess type inference can't reach the `5` through both `decode` and `encode`.

Comment: `encode 5` Likely defaults to `5 :: Integer`, which means serialization will be different from `Int`, therefore deserialization fails.

Comment: @lehins You are correct! `decode (encode 5) :: Either String Integer` works!

Answer (score 3):

The type of `5` is ambiguous, and you are being hit by defaulting. You can either change the type you try to deserialize to to match the default chosen:

```
> decode (encode 5) :: Either String Integer
```

Change the defaulting rules to pick the type you like:

```
> default (Int)
> decode (encode 5) :: Either String Int
```

Or prevent defaulting from happening by making its type unambiguous:

```
> decode (encode (5 :: Int)) :: Either String Int
```

You can read more about defaulting in [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4). Normally this particular ambiguous type would not be defaultable according to the Report, so if you were to stick this in a file and try to load that file you would get an error instead of this subtly incorrect behavior, but in ghci there are [extended defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#extension-ExtendedDefaultRules) that make defaulting happen more often.